# Was the end of the censorship of Magda Szabó's work directly related to events in 1956 or the Hungarian Thaw?

Tags: historical-context, censorship, hungarian-language, magda-szabo

The Wikipedia article about [Magda Szabó](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magda_Szab%C3%B3#Writing_career) says,

> In 1949 she was awarded the Baumgarten Prize, which was immediately withdrawn when Szabó was labeled an enemy to the Communist Party. (...) The Stalinist era from 1949 to 1956 censored any literature, such as Szabó's work, that did not conform to socialist realism.

Since 1956 was a very eventful year in Hungary, it is not clear exactly when and how the censorship came to an end. 1956 saw a power struggle between hard-line Stalinist Mátyás Rákosi and reformer Imre Nagy. At the beginning of the [Hungarian Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_People%27s_Republic#Revolution_of_1956) in late October, Imre Nagy was appointed as the new Prime Minister. After Nagy had announced he wanted Hungary to leave the Warsaw Pact (1 November) and become a multi-party state, Nikita Khrushchev sent the Red Army into Hungary (4 November). Nagy was arrested and replaced by János Kádár. Kádár would eventually also implement reforms that later become known as Kádárism, [Goulash Communism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goulash_Communism) or the Hungarian Thaw.

The articles referenced in the above paragraph mention the release of political prisoners under Nagy but nothing is said about censorship. I am looking for evidence for a connection between the end of the censorship on Magda Szabó's work and events in 1956 (assuming such a connection exists). I am not looking for evidence from other Wikipedia articles that I may have overlooked but from a source that is credible enough to be cited on Wikipedia (e.g. a book or a scholarly article about the history of Hungary or a biography of Magda Szabó).